# use xsl to output plain text

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, plaintext, line-breaks

I needed to use XSL to generate simple plain text output from XML. Since I didn't find any good, concise example online, I decided to post my solution here. Any links referring to a better example would of course be appreciated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="script/command" xml:space="preserve">at -f <xsl:value-of select="username"/> <xsl:value-of select="startTime/@hours"/>:<xsl:value-of select="startTime/@minutes"/> <xsl:value-of select="startDate"/><xsl:text>
</xsl:text></xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A few important things that helped me out here:

1. the use of xsl:output to omit the standard  declaration at the beginning of the output document
2. the use of the xml:space="preserve" attribute to preserve any whitespace I wrote within the xsl:for-each tag. This also required me to write all code within the for-each tag, including that tag as well, on a single line (with the exception of the line break).
3. the use of  to insert a line break - again I had to omit standard xml indenting here.

The resulting and desired output for this xslt was:

at -f alluser 23:58 17.4.2010
at -f ggroup67 7:58 28.4.2010
at -f ggroup70 15:58 18.4.2010
at -f alluser 23:58 18.4.2010
at -f ggroup61 7:58 22.9.2010
at -f ggroup60 23:58 21.9.2010
at -f alluser 3:58 22.9.2010

As I said, any suggestions of how to do this more elegantly would be appreciated.

---

FOLLOW-UP 2011-05-08:

Here's the type of xml I am treating:

```
<script xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="script.xsd">
    <command>
        <username>alluser</username>
        <startTime minutes="58" hours="23"/>
        <startDate>17.4.2010</startDate>
    </command>
</script>
```

Comment: You could save on the number of `<xsl:value>` elements by using `concat('at -f ', username, ' ', startTime/@hours, ' ', ...)`. Besides, you could wrap your source code – if you do that inside the tags, it won't affect the output.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, very short and really generic solution.

Comment: @Christopher Creutzig: Thanks for the great suggestion on concat(). What are you referring to with "wrap your source code"?

Comment: see Mads answer: There's no need to put everything onto one big line. (Although I would not break the line *before* the comma. It just looks weird and does not add anything, not even being able to comment something out more easily.)

Comment: We don't do code reviews on Stack Overflow. I would suggest you reframe your question so it's an actual question (e.g. how to I strip the text out of *this* XML document), then post your draft effort as an answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

- You can define a template to match on `script/command` and eliminate the `xsl:for-each`
- `concat()` can be used to shorten the expression and save you from explicitly inserting so many `<xsl:text>` and `<xsl:value-of>` elements.
- The use of an entity reference `&#xA;` for the carriage return, rather than relying on preserving the line-break between your `<xsl:text>` element is a bit more safe, since code formatting won't mess up your line breaks. Also, for me, it reads as an explicit line-break and is easier to understand the intent.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="script/command">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('at -f '
                    ,username
                    ,' '
                    ,startTime/@hours
                    ,':'
                    ,startTime/@minutes
                    ,' '
                    ,startDate
                    ,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Mads, excellent suggestions. This is exactly what I was looking for. I had forgotten about the useful features of XPath 2...

How is it that &#xA; gives me a new line on windows, when windows usually requires not only a line feed, but also a carriage return?

Comment: @Chris Dickinson Do note, this is an XSLT/XPath 1.0 solution, no XPath 2.0 features used. `&#xA;` (Line Feed) is often enough.  You can add `&#xD;` (Carriage Return) if you need CRLF.

Answer (score 9):

**Just for fun: this can be done in a very general and compact way**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="username">
       at -f <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<script>
 <command>
  <username>John</username>
  <startTime hours="09:" minutes="33"/>
  <startDate>05/05/2011</startDate>

  <username>Kate</username>
  <startTime hours="09:" minutes="33"/>
  <startDate>05/05/2011</startDate>

  <username>Peter</username>
  <startTime hours="09:" minutes="33"/>
  <startDate>05/05/2011</startDate>
 </command>
</script>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
   at -f 09:33 05/05/2011 
   at -f 09:33 05/05/2011 
   at -f 09:33 05/05/2011
```

**Note**: This genaral approach is best applicable if all the data to be output is contained in text nodes -- not in attributes.

Comment: The @* values are missing(and were supposed to be delimited by ':').  Also, not sure whether the leading spaces before 'at -f' in the output would be a problem.

Comment: @Mads Hansen: Thanks for noting this. Fixed now.

Comment: Almost, but I don't think the source XML has ':' in the value of `@hours`. The sample XSL posted is explicitly putting ':' in, not selecting from the attribute value.

Comment: @Mads Hansen: Sure. While I said "for fun", my answer points out a generic method of designing the XML so that the same general and trivial XSLT transformation can be used to generate the output, not needing to know any additional details. As I said in my answer, I wouldn't use attributes and would store the data only in text nodes.

Comment: Tip for [LibXML2](http://xmlsoft.org/) users (PHP, Python, browsers, etc.): if you not use `<xsl:text>` it not strip spaces (!).