# xslt transformation : create a text file

Tags: xslt

Below is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ser="http://xyz.com.zr/l8q/12Q/service/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <ser:User>
            <!-- comment -->
            <Username/>
            <password/>
        </ser:User>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <mainTag>
            <abc>1596056</abc>
            <asd>12434F</asd>
            <def>wert</def>
            <childtag>
                <asdf>1233</asdf>
                <qwe>567</qwe>
            </childtag>
        </mainTag>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Below is my XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="mainTag">
        <xsl:result-document href="foo.txt" method="text">
            01|<xsl:value-of select="abc"/>|<xsl:value-of select="asd"/>|<xsl:value-of select="childtag/asdf"/>|
            02|<xsl:value-of select="def"/>|<xsl:value-of select="childtag/asdf"/>|
            03|<xsl:value-of select="def"/>|<xsl:value-of select="childtag/qwe"/>|<xsl:value-of select="childtag/asdf"/>| | 
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below is the output generated from above xslt
[image]

Below is the text file which contains data from the xslt output
[image]

i am stuck with how i can remove the spaces in the file (screen shot mentioned in the above screenshot)

Comment: Thank you for showing us your content. Now, what is your question?

Comment: i want to write the xslt resulted output to the text file into a directory

Comment: What processor are you using? Saxon or xsltproc receives input and output file paths as arguments at command line. Also any general purpose language (C#, Java, PHP, Python) can save transformed result to file. Be sure to specify [`<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908668/use-xsl-to-output-plain-text)

Comment: xsltproc you can consider it

Comment: Question edited, need help to remove the white spaces in the file which is output by xslt

Comment: Try using `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` after output tag.

Comment: i have used <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>, but still the spaces exists which are shown in the screen shot

Comment: Use concat() with line break. Here is first line: `<xsl:value-of select="concat('01|',abc,'|',asd,childtag/asdf,'|')" /><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>`

Comment: @user2587669 "*xsltproc you can consider it*" That's not possible. `xsl:result-document` is XSLT 2.0. You will get an error if you try to run that on an XSLT 1.0 processor.

Comment: michael.hor257k,Parfait thanks for your information. the solution which u provided worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to eliminate the white spaces from your output is to eliminate them from your stylesheet. Instead of:

```
    <xsl:template match="mainTag">
        <xsl:result-document href="foo.txt" method="text">
            01|<xsl:value-of select="abc"/>|<xsl:value-of select="asd"/>|<xsl:value-of select="childtag/asdf"/>|
            02|<xsl:value-of select="def"/>|<xsl:value-of select="childtag/asdf"/>|
            03|<xsl:value-of select="def"/>|<xsl:value-of select="childtag/qwe"/>|<xsl:value-of select="childtag/asdf"/>| | 
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
```

use:

```
<xsl:template match="mainTag">
<xsl:result-document href="foo.txt" method="text">01|<xsl:value-of select="abc"/>|<xsl:value-of select="asd"/>|<xsl:value-of select="childtag/asdf"/>|
02|<xsl:value-of select="def"/>|<xsl:value-of select="childtag/asdf"/>|
03|<xsl:value-of select="def"/>|<xsl:value-of select="childtag/qwe"/>|<xsl:value-of select="childtag/asdf"/>| |</xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the lack of indent. This, together with:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

will produce the required result.

Of course, it's much more convenient to use `xsl:text` instructions to output literal text, e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="mainTag">
    <xsl:result-document href="foo.txt" method="text">
        <xsl:text>01|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="abc"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="asd"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="childtag/asdf"/>
        <xsl:text>|&#10;02|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="def"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="childtag/asdf"/>
        <xsl:text>|&#10;03|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="def"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="childtag/qwe"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="childtag/asdf"/>
        <xsl:text>| |</xsl:text>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Just a tip, sometimes you can use comments in xsl so you can keep format of code (new lines & indents) and it won't be at the output (as is code comment)